# Java- the final else statement does not execute correctly

Tags: java

I'm having problems getting lines 122 - 128 to execute. I believe I need to add more code but I am stumped. When you iterate through the initial questions "does it have legs?", "Is it a dog?", "Is it a human?", is it an insect?" it is supposed to ask what your animal is, which it does, and then tell you to type a question for which the answer is Yes for insect but no for yourAnimal. Afterwards it is supposed to save yourAnimal, ask you to play again, reiterate through the questions, then ask if the question the user inputs. This is the part where it messes up. If your answer matches your animal, which your playing a second time to guess the animal you input into yourAnimal. It does not do this. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
//add to the questioning below to include a human being and an insect
//add extra code as needed
//clearly comment every line for what is happening
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ThinkingOf2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
           String[] questions = new String[100];
           String[] answers = new String[100];
           String yourAnimal = new String();
           String yourQuestion = new String();
           boolean isDone = false;
           boolean wantToPlay = true;
           int answer1=0;
           int total = 100;
           int pos = 0, oldPos = 0;
           int yesPos = 1, noPos = 2, humanPos =3, insectPos =4;
           // change the questioning to include a human being and an insect
           questions[pos] = "Does the animal you are thinking of have legs?";
           questions[1] = "Is it a dog?";
           questions[2] = "Is it a fish?";
           //I added human and insect to the questions
           questions[3] = "Is it a human?";
           questions[4] = "Is it an insect?";
           answers[1] = "dog";
           answers[2] = "fish";
           //I added human and insect to the questions
           answers[3] = "human";
           answers[4] = "insect";
           while(wantToPlay){
                  pos = 0;
                  isDone = false;
                  while(isDone == false) {
                       //This code only executes if it is the first iteration asking if the animal has legs
                        if (pos == 0 ) {
                            answer1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, questions[pos]);
                        }
                        //This section of code asks if the animal you are thinking of is a dog
                        else if (pos ==1) {
                            answer1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, questions[pos]);
                            yourAnimal = answers[pos];
                            //this only executes if they answer yes to "Is it a dog?"
                            if(answer1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                            {
                                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Yay! I win!");
                                   isDone = true;
                                   pos = 0;
                            }
                            //If the animal has legs but is not a dog this changes the position to position 3
                            //to ask if the animal is a human
                            else if (answer1 ==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                                pos=pos+2;
                                answer1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, questions[pos]);
                                yourAnimal = answers[pos];
                                //if the animal is a human this code executes successfully announcing that
                                //this animal is human
                                if(answer1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                                {
                                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Yay! I win!");
                                       isDone = true;
                                       pos = 0;
                                }
                                //This section of code executes if one agrees that the animal has legs but
                                //is not a dog or a human.
                                else if (answer1 ==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                                    pos=pos+1;
                                    answer1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, questions[pos]);
                                    yourAnimal = answers[pos];
                                    if(answer1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                                    {
                                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Yay! I win!");
                                           isDone = true;
                                           pos = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pos ==2) {
                             answer1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, questions[pos]);
                             yourAnimal = answers[pos];
                             if(answer1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                              {
                                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Yay! I win!");
                                   isDone = true;
                                   pos = 0;
                               }
                         }
                        oldPos = pos;
                        //instead of multiplying by 2, I multiplied by 4 since there are 4 inputs
                        yesPos = pos *4 + 1; 
                        noPos =  pos *4 + 2;
                        humanPos = pos *4 + 3;
                        insectPos = pos *4 + 4;
  
                        if(answer1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { 
                            pos =yesPos;
                            
                        }
                        else if(answer1 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                               pos = noPos;
                        }
                        
                        
                        
                        if(questions[pos] == null)
                        {
                               if(answer1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                               {
                                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Yay! I win!");
                                      isDone = true;
                                      pos = 0;
                               }
                               else{
                                   pos=yesPos;
                                   yourAnimal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"I give up.\nWhat was your animal?");
                                   yourQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Type a question for which the answer is Yes for " + answers[oldPos] + "\nbut No for " + yourAnimal + ".");
                                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "pos = " + pos);
                                   questions[yesPos] = questions[oldPos];
                                   questions[oldPos] = yourQuestion;
                                   questions[noPos] = "Is it a " + yourAnimal + "?";
                                   answers[yesPos] = answers[oldPos];
                                   answers[noPos] = yourAnimal;
                                   isDone = true;
                                   pos = 0;
                                 }
                        }
                  }
                  answer1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want to play again?");
                  wantToPlay = (answer1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
           }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I answer:
No, No, type A, Type B

THen at the end of the final else statement the arrays have the following values:
[image]

So second run of the game if you answer:
No, No

Then Pos = 42 at the beginning of the else statement
[image]

The example above:

1. First no: pos = 2
2. no: pos = 10
3. Because else statements only check for 0, 1 or 2 then none of the if statements at the beginning are triggered, so pos = 42
4. `questions[42] == null` so it asks for the next animal.

Here you can see some code that would work: https://github.com/RobbingDaHood/answers/blob/master/so70824956/src/Main.java

There are multiple changes:

1. The if statements at the root can handle all values of pos, not only 0, 1 and 2 as in your code.
2. The initial array of questions and answers are also setup correctly, according to a tree structure.
3. The arrays are mutated correctly at the when a new question and answer is given.
4. The code is a bit simpler.

Suggestions:

1. Try to use ArrayList instead of Array, because then you are not limited to 100 options (You will quickly use 100 elements).
2. I strongly suggest you learn how to use a debugger; If you IDEA then you can get tra for free: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, happy coding :)